# Search Request View Plugin implemented class

Tags: java, eclipse, jira, jira-plugin

I have updated my request to my current state.
I have left only 1 error and I don't know how to solve it.
First this is my code:

```
package com.example.plugins.tutorial;

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueFactory;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchException;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchProviderFactory;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchRequest;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.views.util.IssueWriterHitCollector;
import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.searchrequestview.AbstractSearchRequestView;
import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.searchrequestview.SearchRequestParams;
import com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraAuthenticationContext;
import com.atlassian.jira.util.JiraVelocityUtils;
import com.atlassian.sal.api.search.SearchProvider;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.providers.LuceneSearchProvider;

import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Collector;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class TestSearch extends AbstractSearchRequestView
{
    private final JiraAuthenticationContext authenticationContext;
    private final SearchProviderFactory searchProviderFactory;
    private final IssueFactory issueFactory;
    private final SearchProvider searchProvider;

    public TestSearch(JiraAuthenticationContext authenticationContext, SearchProviderFactory searchProviderFactory,
        IssueFactory issueFactory, SearchProvider searchProvider)
{
    this.authenticationContext = authenticationContext;
    this.searchProviderFactory = searchProviderFactory;
    this.issueFactory = issueFactory;
    this.searchProvider = searchProvider;
}

public void writeSearchResults(final SearchRequest searchRequest, final SearchRequestParams searchRequestParams, final Writer writer)
{
    final Map defaultParams = JiraVelocityUtils.getDefaultVelocityParams(authenticationContext);

    //Need to put the filtername into the velocity context.  This may be null if this is an anoymous filter.
    final Map headerParams = new HashMap(defaultParams);
    headerParams.put("filtername", searchRequest.getName());
    try
    {
        //First we need to write the header
        writer.write(descriptor.getHtml("header", headerParams));

        //now lets write the search results.  This basically iterates over each issue in the search results and writes
        //it to the writer using the format defined by this plugin.  To ensure that this doesn't result in huge
        //memory consumption only one issue should be loaded into memory at a time.  This can be guaranteed by using a
        //Hitcollector.
        final IndexSearcher searcher = searchProviderFactory.getSearcher(SearchProviderFactory.ISSUE_INDEX);
        final Map issueParams = new HashMap(defaultParams);
        //This hit collector is responsible for writing out each issue as it is encountered in the search results.
        //It will be called for each search result by the underlying Lucene search code.
        final Collector hitCollector = new IssueWriterHitCollector(searcher, writer, issueFactory)
        {
            protected void writeIssue(Issue issue, Writer writer) throws IOException
            {
                //put the current issue into the velocity context and render the single issue view
                issueParams.put("issue", issue);
                writer.write(descriptor.getHtml("singleissue", issueParams));
            }
        };
        //now run the search that's defined in the issue navigator and pass in the hitcollector from above which will
        //write out each issue in the format specified in this plugin.
        searchProvider.searchAndSort(searchRequest.getQuery(), authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser(), hitCollector, searchRequestParams.getPagerFilter());

        //finally lets write the footer.
        writer.write(descriptor.getHtml("footer", Collections.emptyMap()));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    catch (SearchException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

My Problem is the searchAndSort doesn't work

```
searchProvider.searchAndSort(searchRequest.getQuery(), authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser(), hitCollector, searchRequestParams.getPagerFilter());
```

Eclipse shows me the Error that "The method searchAndSort is undefined for the Type SearchProvider".

Same Question and a second example with the same Error:

```
@Override
public void writeSearchResults(final SearchRequest searchRequest,final SearchRequestParams searchRequestParams,final Writer writer) throws SearchException 
{
    final Map defaultParams = JiraVelocityUtils.getDefaultVelocityParams(authenticationContext);
    final Map headerParams = new HashMap(defaultParams);
    headerParams.put("filtername", searchRequest.getName());
    headerParams.put("user", authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser());
    try 
    {
        //Header
        writer.write(descriptor.getHtml("header", headerParams));
        //Body
        final IndexSearcher searcher = searchProviderFactory.getSearcher(SearchProviderFactory.ISSUE_INDEX);        
        final Map issueParams = new HashMap(defaultParams);
        final Collector hitCollector = new IssueWriterHitCollector(searcher, writer, issueFactory) 
        {
            protected void writeIssue(Issue issue, Writer writer) throws IOException 
            {
                //put the current issue into the velocity context and render the single issue view
                issueParams.put("issue", issue);
                writer.write(descriptor.getHtml("body", issueParams));
            }
        };
        searchProvider.searchAndSort(searchRequest.getQuery(), authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser(), hitCollector, searchRequestParams.getPagerFilter());
        //Footer
        writer.write(descriptor.getHtml("footer", MapBuilder.build("user", authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser())));
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    catch (SearchException e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The same problem with the searchAndSort...

It would be very nice if someone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it, I imported the false SearchProvider and now its works.
for others who have the same problem and want to make a search request view plugin witch gives back the issues in html, you can have my code:

```
package com.example.plugins.tutorial;

import com.atlassian.jira.util.collect.MapBuilder;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueFactory;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchException;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchProviderFactory;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchRequest;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.views.util.IssueWriterHitCollector;
import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.searchrequestview.AbstractSearchRequestView;
import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.searchrequestview.SearchRequestParams;
import com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraAuthenticationContext;
import com.atlassian.jira.util.JiraVelocityUtils;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchProvider;

import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Collector;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class NextTestSearch extends AbstractSearchRequestView {

private final JiraAuthenticationContext authenticationContext;
private final SearchProviderFactory searchProviderFactory;
private final IssueFactory issueFactory;
private final SearchProvider searchProvider;

public NextTestSearch(JiraAuthenticationContext authenticationContext, SearchProviderFactory searchProviderFactory,
        IssueFactory issueFactory, SearchProvider searchProvider)
{
    this.authenticationContext = authenticationContext;
    this.searchProviderFactory = searchProviderFactory;
    this.issueFactory = issueFactory;
    this.searchProvider = searchProvider;
}

@Override
public void writeSearchResults(final SearchRequest searchRequest,final SearchRequestParams searchRequestParams,final Writer writer) throws SearchException 
{
    final Map defaultParams = JiraVelocityUtils.getDefaultVelocityParams(authenticationContext);
    final Map headerParams = new HashMap(defaultParams);
    headerParams.put("filtername", searchRequest.getName());
    headerParams.put("user", authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser());
    try 
    {
        //Header
        writer.write(descriptor.getHtml("header", headerParams));
        //Body
        final IndexSearcher searcher = searchProviderFactory.getSearcher(SearchProviderFactory.ISSUE_INDEX);        
        final Map issueParams = new HashMap(defaultParams);
        final Collector hitCollector = new IssueWriterHitCollector(searcher, writer, issueFactory) 
        {
            protected void writeIssue(Issue issue, Writer writer) throws IOException 
            {
                //put the current issue into the velocity context and render the single issue view
                issueParams.put("issue", issue);
                writer.write(descriptor.getHtml("body", issueParams));
            }
        };
        searchProvider.searchAndSort(searchRequest.getQuery(), authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser(), hitCollector, searchRequestParams.getPagerFilter());
        //Footer
        writer.write(descriptor.getHtml("footer", MapBuilder.build("user", authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser())));
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    catch (SearchException e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

the rest you need for the plugin should work of the officele tutorial, [This is the Link](https://books.google.de/books?id=a6sgWTLq3usC&pg=PT371&lpg=PT371&dq=class+extends+Abstract+Search+Request+View+example&source=bl&ots=mRHG3yHn0u&sig=lIo6AOyUM8mEfkXHe5WEH1ETCZI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBGoVChMI66js8L_5yAIVQmdyCh3YEwmM#v=onepage&q=class%20extends%20Abstract%20Search%20Request%20View%20example&f=false) there is the tutorial but the java source code is deprecated.